# Set order for Angular 8 tests

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular8, angular-test

One of my tests fails randomly. I want to set some order for debugging as by default tests run randomly with seed. I tried to set seed number in `karma.conf.js` or set `random: false` but no effect. I use default test configuration and run test with `ng test`. My changes in `karma.conf.js`:

```
client: {
   ...
   random: false,
   //or
   seed: '71384' 
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

this documentation shows how to set test order in karma.conf for jasmine tests.

https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine

in karma.conf you must have (see 'random: false' in config):

```
 module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    client: {
      jasmine: {
        random: false,
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: For anyone trying to figure out how to create the config file: `ng generate config karma`